# Load content (FRONT-END) from two separate WP installation

Tags: wordpress

I'm struggling in an idea to have one main site (possibly WP but not necessarily) which shows contents taken from 3 or more separate WP installations sharing the same DB. The aim is to completely restyle an old (huge) portal and make it as a hub of contents with a vertical structure (News, business, real estate, etc...) each of these vertical site is a separate WP installation. I've currently setup a test environment composed of 2 separate WP installation sharing the same user table, that means a backend user can login in one part and move to the other, that's the first part. Now the problem is how to build the front-end. Is there a way to query the different WP installations to show contents taken from all of them??...
Any idea would be much appreciated.
P.S. I'm not using Multisite.

Answer (score 0):

in WordPress 3.0 there is now a native ability to create multiple blogs, referred to as a network of sites. This is because the codebase for WordPressMU was merged into core.

See this [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) on how you can create a network.

Comment: thanks [soustag][1], I know this possibility, however, my idea was to keep the installations separate and not use multisite...

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/users/3185553/sousatg

Comment: In that case to display the content from the 3 other sites I would recommend using a custom coded solution. Something quick built with Laravel or CakePHP